# FIDO2 Security Key login annoyance with Windows 10/11 and Azure AD

Tags: windows-10, authentication, login-screen, windows-11, fido2

I've a few Windows 10 and Windows 11 machines that are, like I/my account is, joined my Azure AD and I use my FIDO2 keys (Yubikey Bio and also Kensington Verimark Guards) to log in BUT I have noticed one anoyance with both, Windows 10 and Windows 11: whenever the machines boot up I see Windows saying 'Sign-In Options' but, the FIDO2 keys are not 'active' yet.

I always have to switch from my account to 'Other user' and back (in the lower left corner on the login screen) and then the FIDO2 gets activated and waits for me to touch the fingerprint sensor/button and do the usual login thing. Even when I click the sign-in options, the FIDO2 key is not getting activated to read the finger print. This happens with the Yubikey Bio, Yubikey 5 AND the Kensington ones.. all the same.

Whenever I use(d) a Windows Hello compatible fingerprint reader, I could just use it from the get-go and did not have this odd selection of 'Other User' and back to activate the key and I wonder whether there's some setting that might initialize* the FIDO2 keys from the very start.

I've also tried to record the login sequence that might show the annoyance a bit better than just word: https://youtu.be/gxntCutc7cc

**by 'initialize' I mean the FIDO2 blinking and being ready to read your input.*

Comment: At what point in the boot sequence do you insert the key?

Comment: It is plugged in all the time & constantly in that particular desktop machine. What I usually do when I need to log in elsewhere, i.e. on one of the laptops, I pull it out of my desktop and take it along with me, but generally it is plugged in when powering the machine all the way to the login screen.